# Proftpd encrypt passwords

Tags: mysql, proftpd

I have proftpd running that uses mysql db to authenticate users.
If I encrypt mysql passwords, where should I edit in proftpd config to let proftpd know how to match with encrypted passwords? For an example, where should I enter the salt I used to encrypt passwords in mysql? Thanks

Comment: This is probably too large a topic for a simple answer.  The `proftp` package has a dbms interface. Read this and look for the word *hash*. http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/SQL.html  . And, salts that aren't random don't serve any useful purpose.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://serverfault.stackexchange.com is a better forum.

Comment: @O.Jones thanks I will check the link. I will post this in ServerFault.